# **gt** will not format column labels in Word output

Tags: r, ms-word, formatting, r-markdown, gt

Example (`gt 0.9.0`, `R 4.3.0`): column labels for **gt** table should be bold, but are not.

```r
library(gt)
res <- gt(mtcars) %>% tab_style(locations = cells_column_labels(), style = cell_text(weight = "bold"))
gtsave(res, filename = "res.docx")
```

`res` appears correctly in the RStudio viewer.

[image: res_RStudio_viewer]

It is rendered incorrectly in the Word document.

[image: res_Word_viewer]

It seems that **gt** ignores all formatting for columns labels in Word output, including centering and others.

Comment: I think the issue is this note: "Note that only variable fonts may support the numeric mapping of weight."

Comment: @zx8754 Care to elaborate? I don't know what you mean by variable fonts in this context, and I do not see where I made a numeric mapping of weight.

Comment: Probably my comment is not relevant anymore, I tried out some options, none worked. Maybe post your question at GitHub issues.

Comment: Not clear why you don't select the "labels" row in Word and apply the format you want?

Answer (score 2):

this is a problem I've been dealing with for the past weeks as well.
Currently docx output rendering for gt tables is not working (see also [open issues in the gt repo related to docx](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20docx)). They are working on it, but several things that you'd like to work (e.g. cross-referencing) is not functional.

apparently they have these issues to be tackled in [their next milestone 0.10](https://github.com/rstudio/gt/milestone/13)