# How can I convert a gt_tbl object into a flextable object?

Tags: r, gtsummary, flextable, gt, export-to-word

I've been struggling to export my gt_tbl object to Word, because the output ignores all formatting as mentioned in previous posts ([**gt** will not format column labels in Word output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76257780/gt-will-not-format-column-labels-in-word-output))

I thought a reasonable solution would be to convert my gt_tbl object to a flextable and then export as a Word. However, I could not find any function capable of this.

There's a function called as_flex_table from the gtsummary package, but when I try to use it I get the following message:

*Error: Error in argument 'x='. Expecting object of class 'gtsummary'*

I also thought of scrapping the gt table altogether and creating a flextable from scratch, but gt has some features that are too difficult to implement with other packages, such as the tab_row_group function. Here's an example below:

```
table1 <- gtcars %>%  dplyr::select(model, year, hp, trq) %>%
  dplyr::slice(1:8) %>% gt(rowname_col = "model") %>%
  tab_row_group(label = "powerful", rows = hp <= 600) %>%
  tab_row_group(label = "super powerful", rows = hp > 600)

table1 %>% as_flex_table() #This returns the error
```

I really can't find any function to convert a gt_tbl to either a flextable or gtsummary object, please I need some help :(

Comment: Be sure you're on the latest version of gt. Word output is great since the last release. You cannot covert gt tables into any other format

Comment: Also don't use tab_style(). Use cols_label(mpg = md("**MPG**"))

Comment: I would disagree (politely) with the characterization that "Word output is great". It's definitely not. Still can't cross-reference or caption, and I have continued to struggle to get attractive formatting. See this open issue: https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/1140, and a whole slew of others: https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20docx

I get that word is considered passe by many, but in my area (medical research) it is still (by far) the most common